# Is there a way to create a new table type and pass a data-table without a procedure?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm using C# and SQL Server in Windows environment with Visual Studio 2017. I'm trying to pass a datatable (called `@profiles`) to the SQL script.

In order to do so, I first must create a type of a table that matches the data table passed.

Problem is that in every way I tried to populate a new table with the datatable passed I'm getting one of two exceptions:

1. "Column, parameter, or variable @profiles. : Cannot find data type ProfileIdTableType."
2. "The table type parameter '@profiles' must have a valid type name."

From what I searched I could find that a datatable with new table type is generally used with a procedure, but no matter - I still get the above exceptions.

I tried to declare a new table type and use the `@profiles` with it with no success.

When I declare the `SqlParameter` I'm using to pass it, I generally encounter the first exception (can't find the type)

I should mention that I can't find the created type in the "Programmability" section of SQL Server (but my type is temp and so it should be)

These are 2 ways I'm using to pass the datatable to the script from C#:

```
SqlParameter @profiles = new SqlParameter("@profiles", profileIds.Tables[0]);
profiles.TypeName = "ProfileIdTableType";
```

or:

```
DbParameter @profiles = new SqlParameter("@profiles", profileIds.Tables[0]);
```

and then use it:

```
updatedProfiles = (int)DbAdminOps.ExecuteNonQueryCommand(updateProfileSettingsCommand, CommandType.Text, new DbParameter[] { @profiles, @updatedTemplate }, null);
```

This is the SQL script i used last (but tried many variations not presented here)

```
    -- create a table type of profile Ids passed by user
    CREATE TYPE ProfileIdTableType AS TABLE (ID INT)
    go

    DECLARE @PRFL ProfileIdTableType
    GO

    CREATE PROCEDURE PopulateTable
        @profiles ProfileIdTableType READONLY
    AS 
        INSERT INTO @PRFL(ID) 
            SELECT [ID] FROM @profiles
    GO

    @profiles ProfileIdTableType
    EXEC PopulateTable @profiles
    go
```

I expected @profiles be recognized as a table so i can use it in my script but all i get really is exception. I put a lot of effort into it but just couldn't.

Went through all the stack overflow questions, youtubes, microsoft documentation and web.

If there's any information I left out and is important - let me know.

Would really appreciate some advice.

Cheers!

Comment: Use `System.Data.SqlDbType.Structured` for the `SqlDbType` when using table parameters.

Comment: Can you add the code of the stored proc `PopulateTable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key point is to specify SqlDbType as Structured plus to define TypeName as shown in the following snippet.

```
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tvpEmails", dt);
// EMAIL.TVP_Emails should exist on your SQL instance under UDDT types
     comm.Parameters[comm.Parameters.Count - 1].TypeName = "EMAIL.TVP_Emails";
     comm.Parameters[comm.Parameters.Count - 1].SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
```

See the complete code down below. Please let me know if you have any difficulties.

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Net.Mail;

namespace ConsoleApp10
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var mm = new MailMessage();
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection("your connection string"))
            {
                using (var comm = new SqlCommand())
                {

                    comm.Connection = conn;
                    conn.Open();


                    comm.CommandText =
                        @"INSERT INTO [EMail].[MailAttachments] (fileName,fileSize,attachment)
                                             SELECT fileName, fileSize, attachment FROM @tvpEmails";


                    var dt = CreateTable();
                    foreach (var eml in mm.Attachments)
                    {
                        var newRow = dt.NewRow();
                        newRow["FileName"] = eml.Name;
                        newRow["FileSize"] = eml.ContentStream.Length;
                        var allBytes = new byte[eml.ContentStream.Length];
                        newRow["Attachment"] = allBytes;
                        eml.ContentStream.Position = 0;
                        dt.Rows.Add(newRow);
                    }

                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tvpEmails", dt);
                    comm.Parameters[comm.Parameters.Count - 1].TypeName = "EMAIL.TVP_Emails";
                    comm.Parameters[comm.Parameters.Count - 1].SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
                    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                        conn.Close();
                }

            }

        }
        private static DataTable CreateTable()
        {
            var dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("FileName", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("FileSize", typeof(long));
            dt.Columns.Add("Attachment", typeof(byte[]));
            return dt;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: can i create in the code (before using @profiles) the UDDT table i want? - meaning: instaed of this: // EMAIL.TVP_Emails should exist on your SQL instance under UDDT types
     comm.Parameters[comm.Parameters.Count - 1].TypeName = "EMAIL.TVP_Emails";       create this kind of UDDT table in the code like:  CREATE TYPE ProfileIdTableType AS TABLE (ID INT)
 go            and then use @profiles somehow??

Comment: and is it possible i cant start a new line? ;)

Comment: Yes, this is just DDL statement. Be sure that UDDT does not exists before issuing DDL statement. And be sure that the user accont has appropriate rights to execute DDL statement. Everything could be accomplished in the one batch using the same Net cmd. Just insert DDL statement before your DML. I am not sure what your second comment mean.